# Why is this returning one row instead of several?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, data-binding

Why is this returning one value and when I query the database directly I get multiple values?

```
    $statement = $sql->prepare
        ('select * from items where user_id = (select id from user where ?=? limit 1)');
    $statement->bindParam('s', $property);
    $statement->bindParam('s', $value);
    $statement->execute();

    $data = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
 $data = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

try

```
 $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Cool! thanks, do you know why can't I do execute(array($property, $value)) instead of doing the bindParam? For some reason that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: refer #example 2, in this link http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php  and try to pass like that

Comment: that doesn't work. neither does #example 3

Answer (score 1):

You have one problem in your sql, you can't bind columns/table names you must change this `where ? = ?` to `where your_columns_name = ?` in this line:

```
$statement = $sql->prepare('select * from items where user_id = (select id from user where ?=? limit 1)');
```

and to fetch all your records use:

```
$data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: @luis I think that you must read my answer because you have one error in your sql, take a look and correct your code